# TRIAC driver circuit behavior when switching low current loads

Tags: power-electronics, mains, opto-isolator, switching, triac

I'm doing a project that involves switching different kinds of loads (edit: by that I mean loads that go from just a couple mA, up to 5A or so) using the usual TRIAC + opto-isolator combo (in my case, a BTA24A paired with a MOC3063).

I designed it following a couple of application notes from ON Semiconductors that I found online (https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AN-3003.pdf.pdf and https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AN-3004.pdf.pdf) and ended up with 100R resistor + 10nF cap for the snubber circuit, plus a 330R resistor for the peak current limiting in the opto.

My question is related to how this circuit will behave if I used it for switching a particularly low load (say, for example, a LED bulb of some sort).

[image]

Let's suppose I1 = IL =~ 30 mArms (i.e 43 mA peak).
I3 should be pretty small, but let's assume it's 1mA peak. All in all, this will make I2, which is the trigger current, to be around 42mA at the peak.

The datasheet for the TRIAC I plan on using states that the gate trigger current may be as high as 50mA, so given the values mentioned earlier, it could happen that the TRIAC itself will end up not switching at all, and thus all the load current will pass through the driver circuit (and back through the gate terminal) during nominal operation, or at least that's what I'm assuming it will do.

So, the issues I'm seeing are:

- Too much power is being dissipated in the 330R resistor (~ 0.5W).
- Load is losing some good 13V or so to the driver circuit.

Incidentally, thyristors (and TRIACS, for that matter) being semiconductor devices, can be modeled using transistors, right? I couldn't find any curve on the TRIAC datasheet, but I was wondering if in these kinds of cases where you don't have sufficient current for actually triggering the device, it still ends up conducting maybe a little? (i.e does it have some kind of "active region," to draw a parallel with the transistor) Because if so, I would feel more at ease with regards to the whole low-load case.

Comment: Using a 25A triac for driving 40mA load is not a clever idea. You could be using just an optotriac instead.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Sorry, I should've made it more clear in my post: when I say 40mA I'm talking about a worst-case scenario. In practice, the stuff I will be switching could range from a couple mA up to 5A or so.

Comment: You can't switch just a couple of mA, look for latching current, below this parameter the triac won't latch. So your triac should be something about 6A, for example BTA06 has a max. latching current of 50mA, so below this current is useless.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Ah, latching current! That didn't occur to me at all. Mine's seem to be 100mA max. 
Now I see it, thanks a lot.

Comment: Choosing a better TRIAC is better solution, but you may be able to mitigate the high latching current with a small RC load and possibly R if you can live with the losses.